# Probability Inquiry

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 3 Acacias, 4 Narras, and 2 mahoganies be arranged along a property line if one does not distinguish among trees of the same kind?

N = $\frac{9!}{3!4!2!}$ = 1260

**Question** : What if the question says "if one does distinguish among trees of the same kind?

Comment: If the trees are all distinguishable then you just have $9$ distinct objects to permute.

Comment: @lulu Since it does not specify if the acacia will be arranged first, the narra next and so on, so the number of ways we can arrange the nine trees is 9 factorial? 9!?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.